# ECONNREFUSED Error On One Box But Not On Another

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I have a simple Node test script that sends a POST request via https that works perfectly on one Ubuntu box, but fails on a similarly configured (but older version) box. Here's the script:

```
const https = require('https');

const data = 'artist=Betty2%20Hutton2&title=It%20Is%20A%20Good%20Day';

const options = {
  hostname: 'my_server.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/path/to/script.php',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
};

const req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('status code is: ' + res.statusCode);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
     process.stdout.write(d)
    });

req.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error(error)
});

});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

I can get it to work on one Ubuntu box, but on the other one (the one I really need it to work on), I get this error:

> node.js:134
> throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
> ^ Error: ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused
> at Socket._onConnect (net.js:601:18)
> at IOWatcher.onWritable [as callback] (net.js:186:12)

From the box this script fails on, I can ping the host (which is running Apache2), and I can connect to the host + port via telnet, so I know the receiving machine is listening. I can't figure out why this won't work.

Any suggestions you have for diagnosing this will be GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT:

I also tried sending POST data using the request module. My code is:

```
var request = require('request');
var BASE = 'https://my_server.com/path/to/script.php';
var data = 'artist=Betty2%20Hutton2&title=It%20Is%20A%20Good%20';

request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: BASE,
  form: data
}, function(e,r,body) {
      console.log('ERROR' + e);
      //console.log('RESPONSE' + r.statusCode);
      console.log('BODY'+body);
  }).start();
```

This results in:

> ERRORError: socket hang up

EDIT 2:

I'm starting to think it's an SSL problem. If I run this:

```
curl -I http://a_non_SSL_site.com/
```

I get a 200 result code and the other info you'd expect. However, if I curl an https site, I get this back:

> curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Am I correct that this IS an SSL problem and, if so, how do I fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT 3

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, it WAS an SSL problem or, more precisely, a TLS problem. Upgrading OpenSSL fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you using the host name for the ping and telnet commands, or the IP address?

Comment: I used the host name. I just checked it using the IP address (ping and telnet) and that works, too.

Comment: The endpoint is refusing the connection. Does the host have a list of allowed clients?

Comment: I don't know how to check this. I used pretty much the default Apache configuration, modding it to add SSL and PHP. As mentioned, other clients can connect without issue.

Comment: Okay, so you are adding SSL, and that means a new cert. Does the cert need to be trusted in the client side? You typically do this with self-signed certs. I don't know why you would get a connection refused error, but it's worth checking...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. No, the client side does not require the cert to be trusted.